# How can I bind to "ctrl+shift+right arrow" as my default key in manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This recently became possible through the Keyboard Shortcuts customization window:

[image]

However, I've tried ever combination I can think of to try and express this value in my manifest.json. All combinations are resulting in an invalid manifest file. There doesn't seem to be an example for this combination on the website.

Something like this:

```
"commands": {
    "nextVideo": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Right Arrow" },
      "description": "Tells the player to play next video."
    }
}
```

Much obliged if anyone knows the proper string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) says:

> Supported keys: A-Z, 0-9, Comma, Period, Home, End, PageUp, PageDown, Insert, Delete, Tab and the arrow keys (Up, Down, Left, Right).

The arrows are referred to simply as Up, Down, Left, Right. So the value you are looking for is:

```
"Ctrl+Shift+Right"
```

Comment: For some reason I feel like that was my first alternative and it was still yielding an error, but it seems to not be now... so clearly programmer error. Thank you!